# Is there a device for detecting what room you are in of a building?

Tags: localization, bluetooth

I have found some inspiration for creating an smartphone application. But one of the main segments of the app requires it to know where the smartphone is located. It doesn't have to be that precies. It needs to know if you are in office A, office B, the coffee corner, ...

Is there any device/solution for this? I am thinking of an device that sends out a bluetooth connection that a smartphone can pickup in a 5m radius. Or maby a type of nfc tag for a greater radius that a smartphone can pick up?

If there is any app/solution for this idea yet, please let me know.

Any answer is highly appreciated!
Thanks for thinking along!

Comment: Take a look indoor gps

Answer (score 1):

At a corporate commercial scale, there’s devices like the Cisco wireless location appliance https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/wireless/wireless-location-appliance/index.html.

At a hobbyist scale I think the low range beacon strategy you mention could work, but not aware of any products.